# Descarga de archivos por FTP usando C#

Tags: c#, ftp

Estoy con algo nuevo, estoy bloqueado y no se como hacerlo la verdad.

Estoy haciendo un programa que descarga por FTP para hacer una serie de pasos, lo primero es que descargue.

Aquí tengo el código que hace la descarga lo cual funciona perfecto:

```
public static void DescargarFichero(string ficFTP, string user, string pass, string dirLocal, Boolean UsePassive, Boolean UseBinary)
    {
        FtpWebRequest dirFtp = ((FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ficFTP));
        dirFtp.KeepAlive = true;
        dirFtp.UsePassive = UsePassive;
        dirFtp.UseBinary = UseBinary;            
        // Los datos del usuario (credenciales)
        NetworkCredential cr = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        dirFtp.Credentials = cr;

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)dirFtp.GetResponse();          
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);           

        using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(dirLocal, FileMode.Create))
        {

            long length = response.ContentLength;
            int bufferSize = 2048;
            int readCount;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

            readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (readCount > 0)
            {
                writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                Console.WriteLine("Descargando...");
            }

        }

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();

    }
```

Yo estoy haciendo pruebas en una aplicacion de consola, pero el futuro es usar windows form y que se vea bien, mi bloqueo es este: Como hago para que miestras esta ocurriendo esto:

```
while (readCount > 0)
        {
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            Console.WriteLine("Descargando...");
        }
```

Yo pueda enterarme que esa función esta ejecutándose y que esta "descargando" yo estoy buscando que cada vez que ese ciclo esta iterando yo pueda devolver un valor sin tener que romper el ciclo. Mi idea es poder decir Si Valor es = X entonces "descargando"

Pregunta novata? si, estoy bloqueado y no se como salir de la "carrera de ratas". Espero me puedan echar una mano gracias.

Comment: no entiendo que quieres decir, dices que cuando uses windows form como enterarte de que esta descargando como te enteras con console.writeLine("descargando")? Si es así puedes utilizar un label que te devuelva ese mensaje

Comment: Hola que tal, no tal vez no me explique bien. En este momento en mi código estoy imprimiendo en consola, pero claro cada vez que ese ciclo itera esta imprimiendo la frase "descargando..."  si has visto este método esta metido en una función que pertenece a una clase, esa clase la estoy instanciando en otra parte lo que quiero es saber si hay alguna manera de que yo pueda enviar una bandera o algo para yo enterarme que esta en iteracion el ciclo. Con windows form lo que quise decir es que en el futuro implementare esto en windows form pero que ahora lo estoy haciendo en un proyecto de consola.